# How to set array values into state in React JS

Tags: reactjs

I have an array of objects named `resultArray` like

```
[
  {
    "name": "Morgan",
    "category": "on",
    "dept": "A1"
  },
  {
    "name": "Lewis",
    "category": "on",
    "dept": "A2"
  },
  {
    "name": "Ivan",
    "category": "off",
    "dept": "A3"
  }
]
```

In my API result. How can I set them into `state` to get the result as

```
this.state = { 
  person: [
    {
      "name": "Morgan",
      "category": "on"
    },
    {
      "name": "Lewis",
      "category": "on"
    },
    {
      "name": "Ivan",
      "category": "off"
    }
  ]
};
```

Answer (score 0):

initially, declare `person`  key in `state` object with `[]` value like this

```
constructor(props){
  this.state.person = [];
}
```

and to update list use `setState` like

```
this.setState({person : resultArray });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set default data then use `constructor` or if you want to make ajax call then use `componentDidUpdate`. See the example code below.

```
class Mycomponent extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state = {
          person: [
            {name:"Morgan", category:"on"},  
            {name:"Lewis", category:"on"},
            {name:"Ivan", category:"off"}          
          ]
        }
    }
    componentDidUpdate(){
        // make some ajax call to get data
        // now set state like
        data = {
          person: [
            {name:"Morgan", category:"on"},  
            {name:"Lewis", category:"on"},
            {name:"Ivan", category:"off"}          
          ]x
        }
        this.setstate(data)
    }
}
```